# Prematurely interrupting HTTP POST chunked transfer if size limit exceeded

Tags: java, rest, http, http-post, chunked-encoding

There is HTTP REST service  (java, spring boot) it consumes POST requests. It should respond with error code if file larger than specified is transferred. Problem is that client uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and size of file is unknown ahead of request body transfer has been completed.

Service keeps counting bytes received. If counter exceeds a limit. It responds with `413/Request Entity Too Large` and *closes conection*. But client keeps transferring data.

[image: Request wireshark dump]

[image: Prematurely response dump]

It leads to the IOException on the client side:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection$1.write(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:231)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:150)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCache(ChunkedOutputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:234)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime.InputStreamBody.writeTo(InputStreamBody.java:92)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartFormat.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartFormat.java:165)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartFormat.writeTo(AbstractMultipartFormat.java:188)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:109)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(RequestEntityProxy.java:106)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:141)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:218)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionEndpoint.execute(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:712)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.execute(InternalExecRuntime.java:216)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:116)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:188)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:188)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:162)
...
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection$1.write(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:231)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:150)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCache(ChunkedOutputStream.java:127)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.finish(ChunkedOutputStream.java:184)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.close(ChunkedOutputStream.java:245)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:253)
        ... 23 more
```

i tried both `java.net.http` and `org.apache.hc.client5.http` client. And it seems there is no way to get response in case of IOException.

Is it possible to get response error code if IOException? OR more general, what is the *correct* way of prematurely interrupting POST requests with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` ?

Comment: Have you used the Content-Length header instead of writing it all yourself? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length

Comment: Java likes to throw exceptions, make sure a lot of your code is wrapped in try-catch blocks. If the stream gets closed, it will obviously notify you when you try to write to it.

Comment: your image show `Parsing timed out 10000 MILLISECONDS`, check any config about  timeout , 10 sec.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b that's correct. but before closing the stream server responds with  413 code (on screenshot). Is it possible to retrieve response code after catching IOException?

Comment: So are you writing the client or the server? which one has the error and which one is sending too much info? It looks like the client is sending too much for the server to handle.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b both the client and the server. the server should abort receiving post body when it exceeds a limit. the server should support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` ( no `Content-Length` ). the client should know when if the server aborted the reception, but not just generic IOException

Comment: @Denis is the server working properly? Also, throwing and catching exceptions is a necessary part of java sockets.